# Is there a way to pipe the output of one program into two other programs?

Tags: pipe

Sorry if this is a silly question but I'm trying to accomplish something like this but on one line:

```
$ prog1 | prog2
$ prog1 | prog3
```

So, I basically want to execute prog1 and pipe the output to prog2 and prog3 separately (not a chained pipe).  At first, I was trying to use tee but that didn't seem right because it was dumping output to a file (which is not what I want).

```
$ prog1 | tee prog2 | prog3 # doesn't work - creates file "prog2"
```

At some point, I'd probably want to extend this to piping the output to more than two programs but I'm just starting simple for now.

```
$ prog1 | prog2
$ prog1 | prog3
$ prog1 | prog4
...
```

Comment: I think zsh can do this.

Answer (score 32):

Process substitution.

```
... | tee >(prog2) | ...
```

Comment: IIRC that is a bash extension and not found in standard POSIX sh.

Comment: @SimonRichter This is a ksh93 extension, also found in bash and zsh.

Answer (score 17):

Similar to Ignacio's answer, you could use a temporary named pipe using `mkfifo(1)`.

```
mkfifo /tmp/teedoff.$$; cmd | tee /tmp/teedoff.$$ | prog2 & sleep 1; prog3 < /tmp/teedoff.$$; rm /tmp/teedoff.$$
```

It's a bit more verbose, but it would work on systems that do not have process substitution, like `dash`.  The `sleep 1` is to handle any race conditions.

Answer (score 8):

There is a small utility **ptee** which does the job:

```
prog1 | ptee 2 3 4 2> >(prog2) 3> >(prog3) 4> >(prog4)
```

Instead of writing to files, **ptee** writes to all fds which are given on the command line.

**ptee** is part of [pipexec](https://github.com/flonatel/pipexec).

Answer (score 5):

You don't need any bashisms or special files or any of that - not in Linux anyway:

```
% { prog1 | tee /dev/fd/3 | prog2 >&2 ; } 3>&1 | prog3 

{ { printf %s\\t%s\\t%s\\n \
    "this uneven argument list" \
    "will wrap around" to \
    "different combinations" \
    "for each line." "Ill pick out" \
    "a few words" "and grep for them from" \
    "the same stream." | 
 tee /dev/fd/3 /dev/fd/4 | 
 grep combination >&2 ; } 3>&1 |
 grep pick >&2 ; } 4>&1 | 
 grep line

different combinations  for each *line.*  Ill pick out
different combinations  for each line.  Ill *pick* out
different *combinations*  for each line.  Ill pick out
```

I starred the results `grep` highlighted for me to show they were not only three results from the same stream, but they were also the result of separate `grep` process matches.