# How to pipe a command output to multiple programs

Tags: shell

I'm using FFmpeg and I have made a custom application which is a TCP server. I 'm using duplicate output in ffmpeg.

What I want is, for each output I want to start my program to listen on a specific port. For example what I can do now:

```
ffmpeg -i "stream_link" -codec copy -f mpegts - \
    | myprogram -h 127.0.0.1 -p 12345 -f -
```

My program takes the data from ffmpeg and stores them inside the server. Now, I CAN'T DO the following

```
ffmpeg -i "stream_link" -codec copy -f mpegts - -codec copy -f flv - \
    | myprogram -h 127.0.0.1 -p 12345 -f - \
    | myprogram -h 127.0.0.1 -p 12345 -f -
```

I think you got me. I'm trying to output 2 different containers mpegts, flv and open again 2 instances of my program. So how I am able to do it?

This question is only pipe related. I just gave a real example using FFmpeg.

Comment: Probable duplicate, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40277/is-there-a-way-to-pipe-the-output-of-one-program-into-two-other-programs . Andreas Florath's `ptee`/`pipexec` answer particularly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i "stream_link" -codec copy -f mpegts - -codec copy -f flv - |  
myprogram -h 127.0.0.1 -p 12345 -f - | 
myprogram -h 127.0.0.1 -p 12345 -f -
```

So If I understand correctly, you are tryithisng to combine these 2 commands into one.

*mpegts* format

```
ffmpeg -i "stream_link" -codec copy -f mpegts - |  
myprogram -h 127.0.0.1 -p 12345 -f -
```

*flv* format

```
ffmpeg -i "stream_link"  -codec copy -f flv - |  
myprogram -h 127.0.0.1 -p 12345 -f -
```

So, if my above understanding is correct, I believe you can accomplish it using `tee` command.  You could get more details from this question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28503/how-can-i-send-stdout-to-multiple-commands).

So, you could rephrase your command as,

```
 ffmpeg -i "stream_link" -codec copy -f mpegts - -codec copy -f flv - |  
 tee >(myprogram -h 127.0.0.1 -p 12345 -f -) 
     >(myprogram -h 127.0.0.1 -p 12346 -f -)
```

However, as user [mikeserv](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/52934/mikeserv) points out in his comments,

`ffmpeg` is writing two streams to one file. Both the `mpegts` and the `flv` go to **stdout** which is the `|` pipe.

So, the solution would have to involve `ffmpeg` writing to two distinct files.
something like, `ffmpeg flv processing -o flvfile, mpegts processing -o mpegtsfile` and the two processes reading from the two outputs.

Either that or the process receiving the input would have to parse `ffmpeg`'s output to know at which offset to begin reading their intended streams.

So the problem with the `tee` approach is that `tee` could duplicate the `ffmpeg`'s input and two `ffmpeg` could be used.

So a better solution to this problem would be to use the approach as,

```
{ { ffmpeg -i "stream_link"            #one input stream
        -codec copy -f flv /dev/fd/3   #duped and processed, out >&3
        -codec copy -f mpegts - |      #duped and processed, out >&1
        myprogram1 >&4                 #receives >&1 on <&0, out >&4
        } 3>&1 | myprogram2            #receives >&3 on <&0, out >&1
} 4>&1                                 #ensures both myprograms write to >&1
```

When we use the above approach `ffmpeg` explicitly splits its output. It does depend on being run on a system that understands the `/dev/fd/[num]` links.

Comment: does this not send both containers to both `(myprogram...)` instances?

Comment: @mikeserv, yeah. But isn't what the question is about? I believe the OP wanted to send the ffmpeg output to 2 processes. Or am I misinformed?

Comment: yeah. So probably I will wait on OP. But his original question was related to pipes and I thought from his example, he meant to send the first command output to 2 other processes.

Comment: Hello, yes i want to combined everything in one command. Also one output of ffmpeg must go to one instance of my program etc. So for mpegts -> my_program in port 12345 and flv -> my_program in port 12346

Comment: @mikeserv, oh why is it not possible with `tee`?

Comment: @mikeserv, [this](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/6334/use-tee-to-process-a-pipe-with-two-or-more-processes) example explains `tee` and so with the OP's description of the problem, I figured it could best fit his need.

Comment: the wording there isn't exactly correct - `tee` doesn't *split* anything - it *doubles* it. So you can do `echo "one output" | tee >(whole output here) >(whole output here) >whole_output_here`

Comment: Oh ok. I think I get it. But still it is what the OP wants right?

Comment: Thanks @mikeserv. I have incorporated your comments. Let me know if it is fine and feel free to edit if you feel I have missed something.

Comment: I did a little edit - at first only because `\nl|pipe` doesn't work - you need `|pipe\nl`, but then I figured some comments might help. Good answer - we were thinking the same thing *both* times.